# multiple lines in a single line in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have this Select :

```html
Select CASE WHEN tab1.type = 'aaa' THEN tab1.price ELSE 0 END col1,
       CASE WHEN tab1.type = 'bbb' THEN tab1.price ELSE 0 END col2,
       CASE WHEN tab1.type = 'ccc' THEN tab1.price ELSE 0 END col3,
       CASE WHEN tab1.type = 'ddd'  THEN tab1.price ELSE 0 END col4
       FROM tab1
       INNER JOIN tab2
       ON tab1.id = tab2.id_fruits
```

give this result

```
col1      col2         col3    col4
20          0            0       0
0          40            0       0
0           0           60       0
```

is it possible to have

```
col1      col2         col3    col4
20         40            60      0
```

I want to have one line that takes a single value for each column that is different from zero, if all values are zeros, I take a zero
Thank

Comment: Use aggregate max on each field

Comment: You might want to consider using pivot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be one way:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN tab1.type = 'aaa' THEN tab1.price ELSE 0 END) col1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tab1.type = 'bbb' THEN tab1.price ELSE 0 END) col2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tab1.type = 'ccc' THEN tab1.price ELSE 0 END) col3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tab1.type = 'ddd' THEN tab1.price ELSE 0 END) col4
FROM tab1
INNER JOIN tab2
  ON tab1.id = tab2.id_fruits
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the biggest one that is different than 0, use [MAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms187751.aspx)

If you want a number that represent everything that is different than 0, you can use a [SUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) on each SELECT statements.

> Returns the sum of all the values, or only the DISTINCT values, in the expression. SUM can be used with numeric columns only. Null values are ignored.